# Difference between template and templateURL in angularjs ui.bootstrap.modal service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularjs bootstrap modal service.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: "views/myModalContent.html",
  template:"<p>Are you sure you want to delete #"+id+"</p>",
});
```

problem is template content totally replaces templateURL.
But i want that it should keep header & footer defined in templateURL same and just replace the middle part with template, since modal service doesn't have a transclude option. How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use both template and the templateUrl. They are just alternative for one another.

> problem is template content totally replaces templateURL

This is because if you use both of them only one of them would work as of later one.